# Ping ASync Problems

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ping

I have to have a breakpoint on the indicated line below for the following code to work. Otherwise, the program just pauses indefinitely.

```
    async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
    {
        var pingTargetHosts = GetIPs();
        var pingTasks = pingTargetHosts.Select(host => new Ping().SendPingAsync(host, 2000)).ToList();
        var pingResults = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks); //THIS LINE NEEDS A BREAKPOINT TO WORK
        return pingResults.ToList();
    }
```

The code is called like this

```
        List<PingReply> GetReplies()
    {
        var PingIPs = PingAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Loading:...");
        List<PingReply> Results = PingIPs.Result;
        return Results;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me how I need to amend my code in order to remove the breakpoint but still have a functional piece of code.

EDIT:
Not tested, but 99% sure this will work.

```
async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
    {
        var pingTargetHosts = GetIPs();
        var pingTasks = pingTargetHosts.Select(async host => await new Ping().SendPingAsync(host, 2000)).ToList();
        var pingResults = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
        return pingResults.ToList();
    }

    async Task<List<PingReply>> GetReplies()
    {
        var PingIPs = PingAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Loading:...");
        return await PingIPs;
    }

    async Task BuildDictionary()
    {
        List<PingReply> Replies = await GetReplies();
        //Use this list via foreach
    }
    async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EthernetCheck checker = new EthernetCheck();
        checker.Check();
        bool IsEthernetIn = checker.PluggedIn;
        if (IsEthernetIn)
        {
            await BuildDictionary();
            //Do Stuff
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep could help

Comment: what do you mean by 'breakpoint'? `await Task.WhenAll` don't need any breakpoints to work

Comment: Your code itself is causing the block. You are calling `await` while you *already* block the UI thread with `.Result`. Your `GetReplies` method should be async itself, ie `async Task<List<PingReply>> GetReplies(){MessageBox.Show();return await PingAsync();}`

Comment: Who calls `GetReplies`? If the call starts with an event handler you should make all methods up to the event handler asynchronous. The event handler itself should be `async void`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How shall I call the new GetReplies in that case? I need to access the `List<PingReply>` from that task somehow. Originally `GetReplies()` was called by `BuildDictionary()` by `List<PingReply> Replies = GetReplies();`

Comment: The same way as any async method `var Replies=await GetReplies();`

Comment: Another option is to return the Task array returned by `WhenAll` without awaiting. You aren't doing anything with it inside PingAsync anyway:  `Task<PingReply[]> PingAsync(){ ... return Task.WhenAll(pingTasks); }`. This way you only block once, at `PingIPs.Result`. Inefficient but PingIPs it won't block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is deadlocking because you're [blocking on asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). To fix it, use [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

```
async Task<List<PingReply>> GetRepliesAsync()
{
  var PingIPs = PingAsync();
  MessageBox.Show("Loading:...");
  return await PingIPs;
}
```

Usage:

```
var replies = await GetRepliesAsync();
```

Comment: `async void BuildDictionary()
        {
            var Replies = await GetReplies();` is what I'm supposed to do, I assume. Unfortunately, I won't be able to test this for over week.

Comment: @LukeIreland: No; you should avoid `async void`. Use `async Task` instead.

Comment: Do they produce the same result/effect? And can you explain the difference? I read both your artickles, but still not 100%. I've updated the "prototype" on my main post to contain async Task. @StephenCleary

Comment: @LukeIreland: Your new code looks good. I explain the difference in [my async best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - in particular, `async void` has exception handling behavior that is difficult to deal with.

Comment: When "Asyncing all the way", it goes up to a button click event which messes up all my code. How can I separate these parts of code.

Comment: Is it at this point I use async void? See my code in original post.

Comment: @LukeIreland: Yes, you would use `async void` for event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

When use async/await you should remember that .net framework will control the flow of program execution so, I recommend u to make all calls asynchronous to avoid this kind of problem.

```
async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
    var pingTargetHosts = await GetIPs();
    var pingTasks = pingTargetHosts.Select(host => await new Ping().SendPingAsync(host, 2000)).ToList();
    var pingResults = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
    return pingResults.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why use await on GetIPs when it's just used to generate a list? It returns `List<IPAddress>`. Also, I adding the await in the `var pingTasks=` line requires async before host. I can't test this right now, as I'm at home, I'll let you know if this works. Thank you.

Comment: Let us know if it works or if you find another solution. Thank u.